# Can an iPad be charged while acting as a USB host?

Tags: ipad, usb, power

I have an iPad that I would like to leave semi-permanently connected to a USB hub (connected to a couple of MIDI controllers and some USB speakers).  As it stands, I have to remember to unplug it periodically and plug in the charging cable.

I've been looking for a solution that would let me keep the iPad charged while also keeping it connected.  Thinking about it, I realized I don't know if this something supported by the USB standard (let alone by the iPad specifically).

Is it even *possible* to charge an iPad while it's acting as a USB host?

Comment: Normally an iPad will charge when the usb cable has enough power, maybe your hub doesn't have enough power to also charge your iPad?

Comment: What iPad are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Personal experience, I've never it.

But USB specification actually has defined such standard, under [USB On-The-Go (OTG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go#OTG_micro_plugs). A connector named Micro-AB plug will allow a device to be charged and enter host mode. This is also mentioned [here on another Stack Exchange site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a).

Back to the question, is it possible? Probably no. According to [this Wikipedia article about Lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)#Comparisons_with_Micro-USB). A lightning-enabled device can act as host to power accessories or as client to be charged, but it uses either...or, so not at the same time.

Comment: An accessory does let iPad charge when in used, the 30-pin to HDMI adapter for iPad, but the HDMI signal comes from 30-pin, not USB protocol.